# How can i parse oracle tnsname values in c#?

Tags: c#, oracle, parsing

I have a key in my webconfig and i want to get values.

```
<add name="F8CONNECTION" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=PROD)));User Id=$USERNAME;Password=$PASSWORD" providerName="ORACLE" />
```

Ex. I need "HOST" value.

What is the best way to parse it ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer RegEx.

```
var host = new Regex("HOST=(?<host>([a-z0-9]+))").Match("<add name='F8CONNECTION' connectionString='Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhawd1221ost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=PROD)));User Id=$USERNAME;Password=$PASSWORD' providerName='ORACLE' />").Groups["host"].Value;
```